# "cannot read property 'then' of undefined", despite returning a Promise

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, promise

I'm facing what seems to be a common problem, however, I really cannot figure out how to solve it.

I'm calling a function with makes a GET request, parses the returned JSON, and then (supposedly) returns a Promise, which I use to print the parsed JSON data. However, I am getting the error described in the title of this question when I try to do so. I have two files that I'm using. The first simply calls a function from the second, and tries to print the return value (and gets the error).

First file:

```
var secondFile = require('./test');
secondFile.testFunc("some stuff").then(function(res) {
    console.log(res);
})
```

Second file (test.js):

```
module.exports = {
    testFunc : function(address) {
        var params = {
            q: address,
            format: "json"
        }
        var baseUrl = "http://google.com";
        rp({url: baseUrl,
            qs: params,
            method: "GET"})
            .then(function(body) {
                var parsedBody = JSON.parse(body);
                var result = {one: parsedBody[0], two: parseBody[1]};
                return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
                    resolve(result);
                });
            }).catch(function(err) {
                console.log(err);
            });
    }
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: FYI, `return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {resolve(result);});` can be replaced with `return result;`.  Inside a `.then()` handler, you can just return a value and that will become the resolved value of the parent promise.

Comment: Thanks! That does make it a bit nicer to read.

Comment: In cases where you do need to return a resolved promise, you can also do `return Promise.resolve(result);`, though that is not needed here.

Comment: @jfriend00 I'm wondering if it would somehow be possible to call testFunct, then call it again, and then use the results of both functions after they've resolved.

Comment: Yea, get two promises, then use `Promise.all([p1, p2]).then(results => { console.log(results)});`  `Promise.all()` tracks all the promises you pass it and call's it's `.then()` handler when they have all finished and gives you an array of results in the order you passed the promises.

Comment: @jfriend00 Could I ask you about this in chat?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136656/discussion-between-jfriend00-and-miki-p).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`testFunc` doesn't have a `return` statement, so it returns `undefined`.

If you want to take the return value of `rp` (which appears to be a promise) and then return that from `testFunc` then you need to add a `return` statement.

```
    return rp({url: baseUrl,
```

Comment: Yep... I knew it was something dumb. Thank you!